# Error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2019, masm

It shows errors in .data section.
"**array1 BYTE 4 dup (13h,14h,15h,16h,$)**" and "**array2 db 4 dup (12h, 13h,14h,15h,$)**":
**Error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size.**

please help me why and how to fix it..
My code is in below:

```
.data
  
**array1 BYTE 4 dup (13h,14h,15h,16h,$)**
length1 BYTE 4
**array2 db 4 dup (12h, 13h,14h,15h,$)**
length2 db 4
msg1 db 0ah,0dh," $"
msg2 db 0ah,0dh," Max length is:$"
exp1 dw 10 dup ('$')
sample1 db 30h
sample2 db 5h
index db 0
maxlength db 0
num dw 0
cnt dw 0
 
printmsg macro msg
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
LEA dx,msg
mov ah,09h
int 21h
pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
endm
```

Comment: `$` is the current address and doesn't fit in a byte.  Did you want `'$'`, the ASCII character code?

Comment: @PeterCordes - I want it in number..

Comment: `'$'` is an integer constant, aka a number.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes.. what is wrong with it? I want in number. So i think it is correct?

Comment: Again, if you want the ASCII character `'$'` (which is the same as the integer 36) then you need to write `'$'`, not `$`.